# Upload a video to Youtube using Java

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube using the [YouTube API](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java). While running tests using unchanged code the following exception was thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot call getProgress() if the specified AbstractInputStreamContent has no content length. Use  getNumBytesUploaded() to denote progress instead.
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:92)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:49)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.getProgress(MediaHttpUploader.java:934)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.UploadVideo$1.progressChanged(UploadVideo.java:151)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.updateStateAndNotifyListener(MediaHttpUploader.java:907)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:471)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.UploadVideo.main(UploadVideo.java:165)
```

Any idea why and how may I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `getNumBytesUploaded()` instead of `getProgress()`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getProgress()` to `getNumBytesUploaded()`

```
  System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getNumBytesUploaded());
```

It Works you can upload large video.

Answer (score 0):

To get the progress using the `getProgress()` method, the API must be aware of the size of the file you are trying to upload, which you can set using `inputStreamContent.setLength(file.getSize())`.

Or you can simply use `getNumBytesUploaded()` as suggested.